# Agora Screen Sharing without enabling camera (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io, screensharing

I need to start a broadcast for screen sharing and having the callbacks when a user start or stop streaming. But when I enabled the video my camera is algo turn on, is there a way to use screen sharing without enable my camera?

I have read the documentation but didn't find any options to disable camera and still enabling the screen sharing callbacks

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by the Agora team was this :D

```
mRtcEngine.EnableVideo();
mRtcEngine.EnableVideoObserver();
mRtcEngine.EnableLocalVideo(false);
```